# How to make sure that CMake resolves a cmd line argument

Tags: cmake, ninja

My IDE has an internal local variable (resolved by %INTERNAL_VAR% - it is not an environment variable) which points to a folder where my generators are stored (Ninja, minGW32-make...).
I have to pass this path to CMake.
I cannot just write %INTERNAL_VAR% in CMakeLists.txt, because it's local to my IDE, and needs to be resolved beforehand.
And to make it PC-independent I cannot write a fixed value in the CMake files.

So I thought I'd pass it as a cmd line argument when invoking CMake.

This works when setting some local non-cached variables in my .cmake file, but not when setting the CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM variable.

Cmd line:
`cmake -S . -B ./Build -GNinja -DPATH_I_NEED_IN_CMAKE:PATH=%INTERNAL_VARIABLE%`

CMakeLists:

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${PATH_I_NEED_IN_CMAKE}/CMake/bin # OK!
set(tools ${PATH_I_NEED_IN_CMAKE}/GCC/bin                  # OK!
set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM ${PATH_I_NEED_IN_CMAKE}/Ninja/ninja.exe CACHE FILEPATH "" FORCE) # NOT OK!
```

When I invoke CMake I get an error stating that *running /Ninja/ninja.exe --version* failed with The system cannot find the file specified.

I added a message(XA ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM}) after the third set() command, and in the output I get this:

```
XAC:/Users/<user>/path/to/generators/Ninja/ninja.exe # seems resolved OK
XAC:/Users/<user>/path/to/generators/Ninja/ninja.exe # seems resolved OK
XA/Ninja/ninja.exe                                   # does not resolve ${PATH_I_NEED_IN_CMAKE}
```

What gives? Are there any special requirements/limitations when CACHE-ing the declared variable?
I've been going in circles for a while, reading docs, but I don't get what the issue is here.
Any help, tips or tricks are highly appreciated.